# How to set category for PayPal Smart Buttons?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When I view the transaction details in Paypal sandbox as buyer, it says "Category: flights".

Is it possible to change that - or is this automatically determined by Paypal? (The [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-item) only knows about item category physical/digital, but setting this value doesn't change anything.)
[image: Paypal transaction details]

My code:

```
actions.order.create({
    purchase_units: [{
        "items":[
            {"name":"ARGENTINISCHES H\u00dcFTSTEAK","unit_amount":{"currency_code":"EUR","value":"12.50"},"quantity":1,"sku":"FG_001"},
            {"name":"Beilagensalat","unit_amount":{"currency_code":"EUR","value":"3.50"},"quantity":1,"sku":"FG_008"}
        ],
        "amount":{
            "currency_code":"EUR",
            "value":"16.00",
            "breakdown":{"item_total":{"currency_code":"EUR","value":"16.00"}}
        }
    }],
    application_context: {
        payment_method: {payee_preferred: "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED"},
        shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an account setting, not an integration issue.

You can try editing the category of the sandbox Business account you are receiving the payment with, via https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/aboutBusiness -> **Update**

But since it's sandbox, you can also just not worry about it.  The setting in sandbox will not have any relation to any live account this integration ever processes payment with.